# how to convert a variable with both character and numeric variable into a numeric variable in sas

Tags: sas, proc

i looked at the previous links related to the topic and tried using the commands but it is showing error.
i have a variable var1 = **census tract 244.1** which is in character format of length 25. i need a final variable which will contain only the number 244.1 and the format should be numeric

i used the following commands:
newvar = input (var1, 8.)
but it showed error mentioning it as an invalid argument to function INPUT.

i also used:
newvar = input (var1, best32.) but again the same error message as above.

i tried to remove the word 'census tract' word using:
TRACT =tranwrd(var1, "Census Tract", '');
the message said that var1 is defined both as character and numeric variable

i have run out of option. so need help. i'm using sas 9.3

Comment: If you are using a data step, then you should remove the "sql" tag from the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to do this in two steps:

**Extract the characters "244.1"**

Since we're only interested in 244.1, we'll get rid of the rest. This could have been done in a number of ways, one of which is tranwrd as you pointed out.

```
var2 = substr(var1, 13, 6);
```

**Convert the character value "244.1" to the number 244.1**

We need to take the character value and convert to a number. The input function allows us to take a character value and convert it to a number using an informat. An informat is just a way of telling sas how to interpret the value. In this case, treat it as a number stored in 8 bytes.

```
var3 = input(var2, 8.);
```

**Full example program:**

```
data work.one;

   var1 = "census tract 244.1";
   var2 = substr(var1, 13, 6);
   var3 = input(var2, 8.);

run;

/* Show that var3 is a numeric variable */
proc contents data=work.one;
run;
```

**Bonus Info**

Note that you cannot save the converted value back to the original "var1" variable, since once it has been declared as a character variable it cannot store a number. If you did want to keep the same variable you would have to drop var1, then rename var3 to var1:

```
drop var1;
rename var3=var1;
```